# remove cycle reference from Web API Asp.Net Core 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, serialization, system.text.json

I want to remove cycle object reference of my API controllers, by setting the serialization `MaxDepth`. I used the following code in startup.cs but it has no effect :

```
services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(o => new System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions()
            {
                MaxDepth = 2
            });
```

**Note1:** (I'm using .NET Core 5).

**Note1:** I don't want to use `IgnoreJson` on my models properties.

**Note2:** I don't want to use `Newtonsoft`.

Comment: `ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles` is going to be added in **.NET 6**, see [What's new in .NET 6 Preview 2 `[WIP]` #5889](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/5889#issuecomment-781460396).  But it's not in .NET 5, see [Proposal: Add mechanism to handle circular references when serializing #30820](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/30820): *We considered having `ReferenceHandlig.Ignore` but it was cut out of the final design [in .NET 5] due the lack of scenarios where you would really need `Ignore` over `Preserve`.*

Comment: So in .NET 5 you could either [serialize/preserve](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-preserve-references) the circular references or create a custom converter for the classes containing the circular reference, that does not try to serialize the problematic properties.

Comment: @dbc why MaxDepth does not work?

Comment: From the [docs for `MaxDepth`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions.maxdepth?view=net-5.0): *The maximum depth allowed when serializing or deserializing JSON... Going past this depth throws a JsonException.* So I don't think it helps you to remove cyclical references, instead it should abort serialization.  If instead it's doing nothing, that is surprising.  Can you share a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

Now at net 6 and 7 has.

In Signarl Json

> builder.Services.AddSignalR().AddJsonProtocol(options => {
> options.PayloadSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles;
> });

HTTP Works in Minimal API

> builder.Services.ConfigureHttpJsonOptions(options =>
> {
> options.SerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles;
> });

> builder.Services.Configure(options =>
> {
> options.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles;
> });